# URL to room icon in Google Chat (hangouts)

Tags: google-hangouts

Is there any way to find an URL for room icon (or emoji choosed in room settings) from API? Our bot wants to show room list in other apps and it would be great to have also icons/emojis for them.

Regards,
Piotr

Answer (score 0):

#### As far as I know, not possible!

Looks like someone has filed a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/170982288) for this same issue and it has been acknowledged by Google. I would suggest going and starring that issue to let Google Developers know that this affects you.

As can be seen from the spaces object referenced in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces):

```json
{
  "name": string,
  "type": enum (Type),
  "singleUserBotDm": boolean,
  "threaded": boolean,
  "displayName": string
}
```

That's it! It's a very light-weight API! There is no "imageURL" key to call from. A URL does exist (maybe someone else can find a workaround), but its not exposed by the API.

#### Ideas for workarounds

- Get the bot to ask for the icon from the users `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` - you don't have to say "we can't get it from the API", you could say "how would you like it to appear in other apps"?
- Create your own default icon in the same way Google does by using the first letter of the "space". So if the space is called "StackOverflow" the icon would be a large "S" on a randomly colored background.